# TFS Build Server failing

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

Here at my new work, we are forced to use Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008, for our builds.
Even most of developers already moved to VS 2010, and 2012, but the build server is still TFS 2008.
Any way, I am working with VS 2010 project, and I built the "default build definition", on 2008 TFS server.

The build is failing.
Looking at the log, it is trying to delete the workspace "agentserver_104_" but didn't find it, but then later try to create the workspace "agentserver_104_". but it fails because there is already a workspace called "agentserver_104".
This is the error message with the log

```
Target "CoreInitializeWorkspace" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" 
Using "DeleteWorkspaceTask" task from assembly "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.VersionControl.dll".
Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask"
  DeleteWorkspaceTask TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://xxxxx:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/21924" Name="agentserver_104_" DeleteLocalItems=True
  TF14061: The workspace agentserver_104_;TCPL\TFSBuild does not exist.
Done executing task "DeleteWorkspaceTask".
Task "DeleteWorkspaceTask" skipped, due to false condition; 
Using "CreateWorkspaceTask" task from assembly "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.VersionControl.dll".
Task "CreateWorkspaceTask"
  CreateWorkspaceTask TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://xxxxx:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/21924" Name="agentserver_104_" 
  BuildDirectory="E:\TFSBuild\Geofind Modernization\GeoFacility 10.1 - Win7" SourcesDirectory="E:\TFSBuild\Geofind Modernization\GeoFacility 10.1 - Win7\Sources" Comment="Workspace created by Team Build"
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(801,5,801,5): error : The path E:\TFSBuild\Geofind Modernization\GeoFacility 10.1 - Win7\Sources is already mapped in workspace agentserver_104.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(801,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateWorkspaceTask" task failed unexpectedly.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(801,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.MappingConflictException: The path E:\TFSBuild\Geofind Modernization\GeoFacility 10.1 - Win7\Sources is already mapped in workspace DAPP03085_104.
```

Notice that when it tried to delete the workspace, it uses the name agentserver_104_

But the existing name was : agentserver_104

Without the trailing underbar.
any idea?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a problem with probably referenced projects i suppose. Because the real error is `The path E:\TFSBuild\Geofind Modernization\GeoFacility 10.1 - Win7\Sources is already mapped in workspace DAPP03085_104.` So I think you need to check that one.